# how to define a spring bean for this specific xml bean definition element

Tags: spring-test

I am creating Spring bean methods for this following bean definitions in XML form

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.view">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />
```

like below

```
@Bean
public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping urlMapping()
{
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  urlMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.setProperty("index.view", indexController()+"");
    urlMapping.setMappings(props);
    return urlMapping;

}



@Bean
public ParameterizableViewController indexController()
{
    ParameterizableViewController paramControl = new ParameterizableViewController();
    paramControl.setViewName("index");
    return paramControl;

}
```

but urlMapping method definition is incorrect as indexController is a bean..
can you help me correcting the method

Answer (score 0):

In properties you need bean name, and according default bean name strategy in Spring, it is equally method name, in your case:

```
props.setProperty("index.view", "indexController");
```

I just checking application run without any configuration errors.